# Hardhat test failed (offcial example)

Tags: testing, blockchain, hardhat

I am doing Hardhat offcial example to test smart contract.
I did it step by step, but step 5 (testing contract) is wrong for me.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vMqq.png)

It shows something like the img.

Thanks for your help.

I also meet the problem when I deploy the contract.
They are similar the same problem about package -> @nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers.

Comment: Please share more details, like the code involved, a better description of your problem, and your attempts to resolve the problem

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.